# How can I use ViewPropertyAnimator in a ListView with a custom ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a custom `ArrayAdapter` populating a `ListView`. Here it is:

```
public class FilesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PutioFileLayout> {

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    List<PutioFileLayout> data = null;

    public FilesAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<PutioFileLayout> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        FileHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new FileHolder();
            holder.textName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text_fileListName);
            holder.textDescription = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text_fileListDesc);
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.img_fileIcon);

            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (FileHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        PutioFileLayout file = data.get(position);
        holder.textName.setText(file.name);
        holder.textDescription.setText(file.description);
        holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(file.icon);

        return row;
    }

    static class FileHolder {
        TextView textName;
        TextView textDescription;
        ImageView imgIcon;
    }
}
```

I have a `Fragment` that initializes the custom adapter at first with one item, which says "Loading", then does some network stuff, and finally updates the adapter with the real information.

I want to have some kind of animation for when the loading is done and the real info comes in. Maybe a simple fade out. But I can't figure out how I can use `.animate()` on any of my `ListView`'s rows when this takes place.

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your call back just do:
listView.getChildAt(...).animate();

Comment: Sorry, it made me wait 6 minutes. Done.